# Check Any and All keyboard and mouse usage

Tags: vb.net

Does VB .NET have any way of checking to make sure the keyboard and mouse are ***not*** being used?
I know there is a way to test when a certain key is pressed or the curser is moved but I want to check when they have not been used.

Any idea?

Comment: Isnt ***not*** being used just the inverse of being used (via keypress)?

Comment: @Plutonix yes. Either detection method would work I guess. The issue is testing if any key is pressed (not just a specific one) and if the mouse is moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while back I wrote a kiosk app where I needed to detect idle time.  Here is the code that I am using:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Application

   <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
   Private Structure LASTINPUTINFO
      <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
      Public cbSize As Integer
      <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> _
      Public dwTime As Integer
   End Structure

   <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
   Private Shared Function GetLastInputInfo(ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO) As Boolean
   End Function

   Private idletime As Integer
   Private lastInputInf As New LASTINPUTINFO()

   Public Function GetIdleTime() As Integer
      idletime = 0
      lastInputInf.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInf)
      lastInputInf.dwTime = 0

      If GetLastInputInfo(lastInputInf) Then
         idletime = Environment.TickCount - lastInputInf.dwTime
      End If

      If idletime > 0 Then
         Return CType(idletime / 1000, Integer)
      Else
         Return 0
      End If
   End Function

End Class
```

This code should allow you "to make sure the keyboard and mouse are not being used?"

You will place this code into a class.  As needed in your app, you will call GetIdleTime() which returns the number of seconds the app has been idle.  This method is a wrapper around a Windows API call.  So in your example of 5 minutes, you would write:

```
  Dim a = New Application()

  ...

  If a.GetIdleTime() > 300 Then
     'do something useful
  End If
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works (I am newer to vb .net) and how I would use it the way you have? I am also trying to track idle time. If (idle for more than 5min) do this...

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you!

Comment: any knowledge as to why when I try to add the Dim a = New Application() it says "application has no constructors? also could you explain what the structure layout stuff does? thanks!

Comment: You are probably having a namespace conflict with System.Windows.Forms.Application.  So you either need to rename the class or more fully qualify the name.  For example, in my app this class lives in a dll called Utility.  In my code I refer to it as Utility.Application.

Comment: I know the structure is ugly, and quite honestly I never worried about the particulars.  It's just the parameters that the Windows API call needs.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for continuing to take the time to comment and respond on this.

Comment: would 300 in your example be 3sec or no?

Comment: 300 is the number of seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146781/discussion-between-kangarooriot-and-brian-m-stafford).

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Our firewall appears to be blocking chat.