# Run function if there is no action on form for some time

Tags: vb.net

How do I fire an event/run function in vb.net if there is no action on form?

I have tried with this:

```
Private Sub Window_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)

    mint_LastInitializedTimerID = mint_LastInitializedTimerID + 0.00000001


    Dim intMilliseconds As Integer = 5000


    Dim objTimer As New System.Timers.Timer(intMilliseconds)
    AddHandler objTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf Window_TimerElapsed

    objTimer.AutoReset = False
    objTimer.Enabled = True

End Sub
Private Sub Window_TimerElapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)

    mint_LastReceivedTimerID = mint_LastReceivedTimerID + 0.00000001


    If mint_LastReceivedTimerID = mint_LastInitializedTimerID Then
        Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub() showLogin(), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal)
    End If

End Sub

 Public Function showLogin()
    WinUIMessageBox.Show(Window.GetWindow(Me), "!", "...", CType("1", MessageBoxButton), MessageBoxResult.None, MessageBoxOptions.None)

End Function
```

But for some reason, first time it works ok and next time it fires up function alot of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IMessageFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Application.AddMessageFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine when the user types or uses the mouse **anywhere** in your application.  Have your custom filter class raise a **custom event** that your main form (or something else) traps.  Quick example...

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents mmf As MyMessageFilter

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        mmf = New MyMessageFilter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        Application.AddMessageFilter(mmf)
    End Sub

    Private Sub mmf_UserIdle() Handles mmf.UserIdle
        Me.Text = "User Idle @ " & DateTime.Now
    End Sub

    Private Class MyMessageFilter
        Implements IMessageFilter

        Private Enum UserActivity
            WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
            WM_KEYUP = &H101
            WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
            WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = &H200
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201
            WM_LBUTTONUP = &H202
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = &H204
            WM_RBUTTONUP = &H205
        End Enum

        Public Event UserIdle()

        Private WithEvents tmr As New System.Timers.Timer()
        Private SC As System.Threading.SynchronizationContext

        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal TimeOutDuration As TimeSpan)
            SC = System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Current
            tmr.Interval = TimeOutDuration.TotalMilliseconds
            tmr.Start()
        End Sub

        Private Sub Reset()
            tmr.Stop()
            tmr.Start()
        End Sub

        Private Sub tmr_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles tmr.Elapsed
            ' raise the event in a thread safe manner
            If Not IsNothing(SC) Then
                SC.Post(New System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf GuiSafeRaiseEvent), Nothing)
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub GuiSafeRaiseEvent() ' do not call me directly!
            RaiseEvent UserIdle()
        End Sub

        Private Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message) As Boolean Implements System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
            Select Case m.Msg
                Case UserActivity.WM_KEYDOWN, UserActivity.WM_KEYUP, UserActivity.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, UserActivity.WM_LBUTTONUP, UserActivity.WM_MOUSEMOVE, UserActivity.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, UserActivity.WM_RBUTTONUP, UserActivity.WM_SYSKEYDOWN, UserActivity.WM_SYSKEYUP
                    Me.Reset() ' the user did something, reset the timer

            End Select

            Return False ' allow normal processing to occur for all messages
        End Function

    End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're creating a new handler every millisecond that the mouse is in motion. I'd think you would want to create the timer when the form loads, then reset it to 0 each time the mouse moves.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/44552767/5162073.  You can respond as needed after any amount of idle time.

```
  If a.GetIdleTime() > 300 Then
     showLogin()
  End If
```